# How can I make a Rate-Button in iOS7?

Tags: xcode, button, ios7, rate

I want to add a rate-button to my application. How can I do this?

```
- (IBAction)rateGame {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID"]];         
}
```

In the simulator, this doesn't work. (Can't test it on a real device right now)

Is this the correct way to do this or should I try something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct for launching the App Store with the app page open; I use the same code in my shipping app. This is the best you can achieve on iOS 7. It doesn't work on the iOS Simulator because the simulator doesn't have the App Store or iTunes apps installed, so there's nothing to launch.

Comment: itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID

My app is not in app store yet so i'm currently thinking of making Rate button too. Doesn't the above link launch the iTunes store for music and not the app store for iPhone/iPad apps?  Why did you say it launches the app store then?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate). Handle all network connection and other related issues. And easy to implement. Just drag and drop files to your `AppDelegate`. It automatically configures all the required terms(like app store id, etc) from the `info.plist` files, and gets all the required information from app store.

NOTE: iRate can be used without any configuration, just by dragging and adding the files to project. [See this example](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/tree/master/Examples/Zero%20Config%20Demo).

```
#import "iRate.h" 

        @implementation AppDelegate

        + (void)initialize
        {
            //configure iRate
            [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = YES;// yes for testing
        }
```